# How to remove specific Azure Web App instance?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, autoscaling

I am testing auto scale in/out on Azure Web App. However, the auto-scaling rules don't have the ability to specify which instance to remove. I think the reason is obvious as the instances are started up dynamically.

The issue is I want to choose which instance to turn off for different reasons. From Azure Powershell I can get the instances that are running, but I can't find anything to remove specific instance for scale-in. Any help?

The reason for this requirement is the app does use session states(legacy issue) and not easy to remove that cheaply. I don't want to turn off the instance which is already under use, but only those ones which have none or under light load. Using [Redis Cache for session](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-session-state-caching/) would be last consideration, but it would be expensive too.

Comment: It is not possible in web apps. If it is a role instance then it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to take a look at [Azure Service Fabric](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-introduction/#example-services), which handles stateful tiers flawlessly, but the "legacy issue" part of the question might be a deal breaker

> In Service Fabric, stateful services aren't required to store their state externally; Service Fabric takes care of these requirements for both the service code and the service state.

Answer (score 0):

We also have a legacy application planning to migrate to Azure with Load Balancing Enabled. Instead of using Redis or similar distributed cache mechanisms, we just are planning to go with ARR affinity cookie enabled. Please have a look at http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-app-service-sessions-management-in-load-balancing-environment-using-redis/ for more details..

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the information, we have considered about that. We put Redis as last solution is because of the size of our session data (we probably should solve this somehow at the end but not soon). And Redis Cache is expensive. And I don't know how well Redis handles session write conflict. Have you had any experience with that?